# Gaussian curve fitting in physics

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have this data, I tried to fit by a Gaussian function but I can't found an appropriate function, I tried using curve_fit from scipy.optimize :

```
time_s = [1.44692600e+09, 1.44692634e+09, 1.44692671e+09, 1.44692707e+09,
 1.44692743e+09, 1.44692785e+09, 1.44692826e+09, 1.44692941e+09,
 1.44692967e+09, 1.44692997e+09, 1.44693029e+09, 1.44693062e+09,
 1.44693096e+09, 1.44693131e+09, 1.44693200e+09, 1.44693227e+09,
 1.44693254e+09, 1.44693284e+09, 1.44693313e+09, 1.44693342e+09,
 1.44693370e+09, 1.44693398e+09, 1.44693429e+09, 1.44693460e+09,
 1.44693492e+09, 1.44693522e+09, 1.44693552e+09, 1.44693586e+09,
 1.44693620e+09, 1.44693652e+09, 1.44693683e+09, 1.44693713e+09,
 1.44693744e+09, 1.44693775e+09, 1.44693804e+09, 1.44693831e+09,
 1.44693858e+09, 1.44693886e+09, 1.44693914e+09, 1.44693941e+09,
 1.44693967e+09, 1.44693993e+09, 1.44694020e+09, 1.44694047e+09,
 1.44694075e+09, 1.44694102e+09, 1.44694130e+09, 1.44694160e+09,
 1.44694190e+09, 1.44694220e+09, 1.44694251e+09, 1.44694284e+09,
 1.44694319e+09, 1.44694356e+09, 1.44694392e+09, 1.44694427e+09,
 1.44694464e+09, 1.44694505e+09, 1.44694546e+09, 1.44694586e+09,
 1.44694624e+09, 1.44694662e+09, 1.44694703e+09, 1.44694744e+09]

Temperature = [829.331306, 931.702088, 890.075633, 830.659093, 878.715978, 866.238768
, 897.958014, 940.495055, 841.990924, 875.391469, 898.393043, 925.048353
, 931.445104, 904.151363, 965.550728, 916.348809, 936.315168, 900.445995
, 887.76832,  875.064126, 881.480871, 878.240278, 862.958271, 893.813659
, 883.678318, 923.593998, 915.52458,  877.919073, 891.754242, 919.274917
, 862.223914, 881.275387, 862.33147,  869.461632, 890.014577, 902.656117
, 874.446393, 876.284046, 866.751916, 854.095049, 844.540741, 870.263794
, 866.687327, 818.019291, 821.875267, 813.385138, 843.198211, 870.558259
, 794.039978, 813.497634, 812.217789, 801.361143, 800.263045, 747.101493
, 735.923635, 732.930255, 775.930026, 783.786631, 775.255742, 774.938671
, 704.186773, 747.612911, 729.315237, 694.021293]
```

[image: data plotting]

I used this code :

```
def Gauss(x, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2 ):
    return a1*np.exp(-((x-b1)/c1)**2) + a2*np.exp(-((x-b2)/c2)**2)
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(Gauss, time_s, Temperature)
plt.plot(time_s, Gauss(time_s, *parameters))
plt.show()
```

this is the result of this fit :
[image: bad fit]

Very bad fit

The error message :

```
/home/lhoussine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:828: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
```

Comment: Scipy has a [curve_fit funciton](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: So, what code have you tried, and what specific problem did you encounter? An error message? The fit was not good? No output whatsoever? We don't know, so we cannot help you.

Comment: This is an exemple of the functions I tried with : ` def Gauss(x, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2 ):
        return a1*np.exp(-((x-b1)/c1)**2) + a2*np.exp(-((x-b2)/c2)**2) ` and this is the reerror : `/home/lhoussine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:828: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
`

Comment: You're not fitting a Gaussian, that's a _sum_ of two Gaussians. You'll almost certainly need to provide some initial guesses as well -- the default value of 1 is pretty terrible for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not fitting a Gaussian function, you're fitting the sum of a couple of functions. I'm not sure why, but it certainly doesn't help and doesn't match your question.

But even if we fit a single Gaussian, the main problem is the initial guess for `curve_fit`. Unless you say otherwise, [the default for all parameters is `1`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html?highlight=curve_fit#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). That's a truly abysmal initial guess in your case, given that you appear to be fitting timestamps on the order of 1e9.

If you provide even rough estimates for the initial guesses, `curve_fit` is actually able to do a pretty decent job:

```py
def gaussian(x, amplitude, mean, sd):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-(x - mean) ** 2.0 / sd ** 2.0)

parameters, covariance = curve_fit(gaussian, time_s, Temperature, p0=(900, np.mean(time_s), 1000))
plt.plot(time_s, Temperature)
plt.plot(time_s, gaussian(time_s, *parameters))
```

This gives us:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir so much, I worked on this for a long time, I'm very grateful